# Java : Use Disruptor or Not . .

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Hy,

Currently I am developing a program that takes 2 values from an amq queue and performs a series of mathematical calculations on them. A topic has been created on the amq server to which my program subscribes and receive messages via callbacks (listeners).

Now whenever a message arrives the two values are taken out of and added to the SynchronizedDescriptiveStatistics object. After each addition to the list of values the whole sequence of calculations is performed all over again (this is part of the requirement actually).

The problem I am facing right now is that since I am using listeners, sometimes a single or more messages are received in the middle of calculations. Although SynchronizedDescriptiveStatistics takes care of all the thread related issues it self but it adds all the waiting values in its list of numbers at once when it comes out of lock or something. While my problem was to add one value then perform calcls on it then second value and on and on.

The solution I came up with is to use job queues in my program (not amq queues). In this way whenever calcs are over the program would look for further jobs in the queue and goes on accordingly.

Since I am also looking for efficiency and speed I thought the Disruptor framework might be good for this problem and it is optimized for threaded situations. But I am not sure if its worth the trouble of implementing Disruptor in to my application because regular standard queue might be enough for what I am trying to do.

Let me also tell you that the data on which the calcs need to be performed is a lot and it will keep on coming and the whole calcs will need to be performed all over again for each addition of a single value in a continuous fashion. So keeping in mind the efficiency and the huge volume of data what do you think will be useful in the long run.

Waiting for a reply. . .

Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll give our typical answer to this question: test first, and make your decision based on your results.

Although you talk about efficiency, you don't specifically say that performance is a fundamental requirement.  If you have an idea of your performance requirements, you could mock up a simple prototype using queues versus a basic implementation of the Disruptor, and take measurements of the performance of both.

If one comes off substantially better than the other, that's your answer.  If, however, one is much more effort to implement, especially if it's also not giving you the efficiency you require, or you don't have any hard performance requirements, then that suggests that solution is not the right one.

Measure first, and decide based on your results.